# Why Chrome use random Cipher Suites?

Tags: ssl

In SSL handshake protocol When looking at client Cipher Suites that Chrome browser sends using WireShark, it shows that the first item is always some random value, why are they doing this? Is it part of SSL protocol? Where it comes from?

[image: Wireshark log]

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature to prevent servers to get buggy. From [GREASE for TLS](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6475903378915328):

> TLS clients offer lists of 16-bit code points (e.g. cipher suites) that servers select from. To remain extensible, servers must ignore unknown values. However, servers may have bugs and reject unknown values. These servers will interoperate with existing clients, so the mistake may spread unnoticed, breaking extensibility for the whole ecosystem. **We will reserve some values to advertise at random**, to prevent such mistakes before broken servers are widespread.

See also [Google Chrome weird random Cipher Suite](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176951/google-chrome-weird-random-cipher-suite) at security.stackexchange.com for more details, like reference to the source code and internet draft.